# Is there a command for opening emacs in shell mode?

Tags: shell, start-up

Suppose I want to open emacs with a file and shell mode together. If there were two files I would do `emacs file1 file2` and emacs opens them both. Is there a command to do this with `emacs file [shell]`?

Answer (score 3):

The following works with emacs26 on Ubuntu:

```
emacs file --eval "(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'shell)"
```

Adding the function `#'shell` to `emacs-startup-hook` (instead of calling it with `-f shell`) defers the call to `shell` until the initialization of Emacs is complete.

That way the `*shell*`-buffer will be displayed in the window that is used for the `*scratch*` buffer when there is no other configuration in the init file of Emacs. Eventual, only the two buffers you are interested in, `file` and `*shell*`, will be displayed at startup.

See the [doc of the startup sequence of Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html).

Answer (score 2):

Pass the [command line option](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html#Action-Arguments) `-f` to run a function with no arguments, or `--eval` to run an arbitrary Lisp expression.

To run a shell (whichever comes last is the one that's displayed in the Emacs window):

```
emacs filename.txt -f shell
emacs -f shell filename.txt
```

Here are examples to split the window or open two frames.

```
emacs -f shell -f split-window-vertically filename.txt
emacs -f shell -f split-window-vertically filename.txt -f other-window
emacs -f shell -f make-frame filename.txt
```